# Defining XML tag dynamically based on object property

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I just can't get my head around this one.

I have an object called PermissionDto:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "permission")
@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class PermissionDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Link entity;

    ... some other properties, constructors and getters
}
```

This will produce the following JSON:

```
   {
       "entity":
       {
           "rel": "users",
           "href": ...
       }
    }
```

The entity rel can be (currently) "users" or "roles". What I would like would be to produce the following JSON when rel is "users":

```
   {
       "users":
       {
           "rel": "users",
           "href": ...
       }
    }
```

and when the rel is "roles":

```
   {
       "roles":
       {
           "rel": "roles",
           "href": ...
       }
    }
```

without having to create a UserPermissionDto and another RolePermissionDto considering they are exactly the same except for this one property. I can do entity.getRel() in order to know the rel of the Link.

Please note my server can also produce XML representations of these responses which means the tag for response

```
<entity rel="users" href="http://localhost:8080/users/1"/>
```

should also be represented as indicated above (either "users" or "roles" instead of "entity").

I use JAXB for XML and Jackson for JSON.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check `@XmlElements`, it allows different element names depending on the type (probably your case). Not sure if it works for JSON but it's worth giving it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually turned the problem upside down and found a better solution.

We decided to try to implement our API in full HATEOAS fashion. In this way, users and roles are nothing more than links to those specific entities.

By using [Spring HATEOAS Project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/) PermissionDto was refactored to a PermissionResource which extends from ResourceSupport. This means a PermissionResource can be composed with either user or role URIs dependending on which [Permission Resource Assembler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/readme.md#resource-assembler) is being used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work for JSON but try `@XmlElements`:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="users", type=Users.class),
    @XmlElement(name="roles", type=Roles.class)
}
public Link entity;
```

This assumes `Users` and `Roles` extend `Link`. In this case, depending on whether your object has an instance of `Users` or `Roles`, you'll get `users` or `roles` element names. Not sure about JSON.

It may well be that this only works for collection properties.

Comment: Hey @lexicore, unfortunately this is not the case. Users and Roles do not extend Link, they are transformed into Link by getting their type as rel and their id to form the href (this maintains domain objects separate from DTO objects which communicate with the client).

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment: Users and Roles do not even share a common superclass

Comment: Working on a new implementation. This was a massive help, thank you.